# StatusBar gets Back after returning back to the app, why?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, android-statusbar, android-fullscreen

This is my app.js in NativeScript + Vue:

```sh
import Vue from "nativescript-vue";

new Vue( {

    template: `<Frame actionBarVisibility="never" ></Frame>` ,

    methods: {
        fullScreenApplier () {
            var app = require("application");
            var platform = require("platform");
            var View = android.view.View;
            if ( app.android && platform.device.sdkVersion >= '21' ) {
                var window = app.android.startActivity.getWindow();
                var decorView = window.getDecorView();
                decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                );
            }
        } 
    }  ,

    mounted () { this.fullScreenApplier(); } 

} ).$start();
```

it hides the `StausBar`, but if I minimize the app and again return back to it, the `StatusBar` remains on Top permanently unless I kill it.

Whats the problem here?

Comment: Try calling the `fullScreenApplier()` method upon loaded event of Frame.

Comment: @Manoj Thanks alot, could you explain why it works properly by your suggestion? I even had tried to call it by tapping but it wouldn't help.

Comment: Loaded event is called upon resume too, so it applies the settings on Activity back.

Answer (score 0):

It works as @Manoj suggested by calling `fullScreenApplier()` in `@loaded`,

but there is another problem,

when I call this one:

```
permissionApplier () {
   permissions.requestPermission ( [
      "android.permission.INTERNET" ,
      "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
   ] );
}
```

it returns back the `StatusBar` again.

What Can I do for this problem?

Comment: Are you testing on local app or Playground?